# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on hardrive of Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, 17.04

need your help again!

I'm using ubuntu 17.04 right now alongside windows 7. I want to install ubuntu 16.04. **How can I remove ubuntu 17.04 (I found some graphical issues here) and install 16.04 on that drive?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to remove ubuntu 17.04 before, just do a 16.04 clean install into the same partition where 17.04 is now installed, using your preferred install media.

Comment: This^^^ Use the "Something else"option and select the existing partitions except swap which is "recyclable". But that will be a wast of time. **The "graphical issues" will be the some or worse**. What you should be asking instead is *how to solve the "graphical issues".

Comment: Open the install media and install Ubuntu, choosing the "something else" option and tell us what shows up. Do not continue with install.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) tutorial should help you a long way.

Edit:

1. Backup your files.
2. Delete the linux partition(s). most installs have a partition dedicated to  `/`, `/boot` and sometimes to `/home`. Delete the linux swap partition if present. Delete the bootloader partition if present.
3. Restore the MBR using a windows repair usb. This might differ slightly depending on your operating system.
4. There is now some unpartitioned space on your harddisk. You could grow your windows partition to span that empty space. (This might not be desireable if you have an ssd and use over provisioning.)

Comment: This is not an answer. Include the relevant portions of the linked article in case the site goes offline, changes, or is not reachable. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips.

Comment: The answer is about removing ubuntu, and does not take into account the possibility of UEFI.